# WP Как переместить метабокс с боковой панели в главную?

Tags: wordpress

Стоит задача по перемещению метобокса `postexcerpt – «Отрывок»` с боковой панели задач редактора в основную.

[image: postexcerpt]

Согласно документации, сначало необходимо [деактивировать remove_meta_box()](https://misha.agency/wordpress/remove_meta_box.html), а потом [подключить где надо](https://misha.agency/wordpress/meta-boxes.html). При этом надо помнить о приоритетах отключения и добавления.

Немогу понять, что я делаю не так, что у меня оно даже не отключаеться.

```
function move_excerpt_metabox() {
    remove_meta_box('postexcerpt', array( 'post', 'page' ), 'side');
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', array( 'post', 'page' ), 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'move_excerpt_metabox', 25 );
```

В чем ошибка ?

Comment: В Gutenberg это не метабокс, потому будет ошибкой пытаться работать с этим как с метабоксом. Для удаления нужно использовать `wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel('post-excerpt');`. Почитайте в [Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-edit-post/#removeeditorpanel)

Comment: Метабоксы есть только в классическом редакторе. И в админке они перемещаются мышей. А отрывок по умолчанию под основным редактором.

Comment: На текущей теме стоит Gutenberg редактор. Но почкму-то конкретно это поле Drag&Drop -опом передвинуть не получаеться.

Comment: Ну потому что в гутенберге это так не работает) В предыдущем комментарии речь была о классическом редакторе.

Comment: @Simon А можно более наглядный пример как сделать данный Блок перетягиваемым? Мне по сути не надо его отключать, просто сделать что б он отображался по центру редактора. *Я опробовал на дефолтных темах он там тоже фиксирован по положению.

Comment: Перетягиваемым в Gutenberg Вы его не сделаете скорее всего (хотя наверное можно, но не уверен), но можно удалить существующий и написать собственный, если хотите, то могу расписать, только для этого Вам так же нужен будет бандлер, так как для этого потребуется пара npm пакетов + будет испольховаться JSX синтаксис.

Comment: Был бы очень признателен, если б показали.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 окей, я только что пошел попробовать и все гораздо проще на деле) Можете просто удалить сам этот эксерпт из боковой панели посредством `wp.domReady(() => wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel('post-excerpt'));` и потом добавить эксерпт как метабокс, только из своей фукции `move_excerpt_metabox()` уберите `remove_meta_box()`. Это наверное самый оптимальный и простой вариант, так как для этого редактора размещение такого рода полей в боковой панели есть стандартом, а с тем чтобы это размещать иначе, нужно потанцевать с бубном.